# Multi-threaded linux antivirus software that works with new kernels

Tags: linux, anti-virus, file-server

**Q1:** Does anyone know of some real-time, on-access protection antivirus software for linux, that is capable of fully utilizing multi-core processors of today?

I am having issues using KAV for Samba, as while it does its on-access scanning, files are being accessed by many clients and that creates a bottleneck on server, as it scans (almost) every file on open.

Another problem that I have with KAV is that it won't work with kernels newer than 2.6.26, which is a problem, since it won't work with new hardware (which requires new kernel versions).

**Q2:** Does anyone knows of on-access antivirus software for linux that works with newest kernels? A big plus is if one has used software with success.

If anyohe has an idea about solving one (or both) of these problems, please!

I have tried to configure samba-vscan wth ClamAV, but no luck there (some weird error during compiling of samba-vscan module).

By the way, server is being used as samba server, in a network of clients, running Debian-based distro (if it matters anyway).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a little Google checking and ClamAV *claims* to support both multi-threaded and on-demand scanning.  See [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/clamav/0.96.1+dfsg-0ubuntu0.10.04.1) for the 0.96.1 release early-to-mid 2010.  They [offer help in a few ways](http://www.clamav.net/lang/en/support/) that should hit your questions directly. This includes forums, a wiki, and even paid support.  If this is an employer-directed action, ask them to buy some support so that you can make some progress.

I saw a hint that the Dag Wieers repository may have one prebuilt, but I'm having trouble browsing the repository either on his website or rpmforge.net.

By the way, kernel-based on-access scanning is still not merged [the last time I checked](http://lwn.net/Articles/409955/).  That said, we were able to get the newest Symantec Endpoint to run on some RedHat 5 boxes.  I wasn't privy to the details as far as problems and such.  I also don't know if there is a Debian distribution or if it is on-access scanning.

Comment: Were you satisfied with Symantec Endpoint, performance-wise?

Comment: We don't hate it.  We also don't let it run on our servers, just desktops.  I don't know about it's performance server-side.  Nothing noticeable on the desktop - it integrates nicely and stay out of my way.  Mainly there for to be a checked box on our security checklist.

Comment: ClamAV "supports" on-access scanning, using external, clamfs utility (you remount target directory structure as on-access scanned directory, courtesy of clamd). Marking it as an answer.